# SimpleDateFormat did not work

Tags: java, android, time

I wanted to change the format (from 12 to 24hours) saves your time and found on stack how to do it

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

String currentDateTimeString = dateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

but not that still works and saves Form A.M/P.M

why it does not work?

Comment: What do you expect these two lines of code to do, and what do they do instead? Note that `mm` means minutes, not months.

Comment: This is the answer from many points of reputation, I thought that it is well

Comment: Can you please link to the answer you're referring to?

Comment: Also, you should never, ever copy and paste code from here without understanding it first. Read the javadoc. It's not that difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call the static method `getDateTimeInstance()`, which creates a new SimpleDateFormat instance, instead of using the SimpleDateFormat you just created:

```
dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Also, you're using `mm` (minutes) instead of `MM` (months).

Comment: That method is static, so does that mean they actually did `DateFormat` instead of `dateFormat`? Otherwise it shouldn't have compiled.

Comment: @4castle You can call static methods via an instance. It works fine.

Comment: You can even call a static method on a null reference. This is a big design mistake from the early days of Java.